# Schema evolution with Autoloader

Tags: pyspark, merge, schema, azure-databricks, databricks-autoloader

I have a schema evolution case.

Detailed description:

Im laoding the source tables from datalake to bronze layer aas row data using autoloader and foreachbatch with function of merge into statemenet. which is having no problem to do the job.

While moving from bronze to sivler, as a source table I apply the `select` statement to filter out extra columns when moving into silver layer.

I have the problem with only one table.

Table `customeraddress` in the Bronze layer have the column `MSFT_DATASTATE` which is not the case of the same table in silver layer. So i want to add this column autoamtically to my silver table.

```
# Enable autoMerge for schema evolution
spark.conf.set("spark.databricks.delta.schema.autoMerge.enabled", "true")

p = re.compile('^BK_')
list_of_columns = dfUpdates.columns
list_of_BK_columns = [ s for s in dfUpdates.columns if p.match(s) ]
string = ''
for column in list_of_BK_columns:
    string += f'table.{column} = newData.{column} and '
dictionary = {}
for key in list_of_columns:
    dictionary[key] = f'newData.{key}'

# print("printing " + cdm + " columns")
print("We at this stage now -----------------------------------------------------")
# print(dfUpdates.columns)

deltaTable = DeltaTable.forPath(spark, f"abfss://silver@{storage_account}.dfs.core.windows.net/D365/{table.lower()}_ao")
deltaTable.alias('table') \
    .merge(dfUpdates.alias("newData"), string) \
    .whenMatchedUpdate(set=dictionary) \
    .whenNotMatchedInsert(values=dictionary) \
    .execute()

df.writeStream.foreachBatch(lambda df, epochId: update_changefeed(df, table, epochId)).option("checkpointLocation", checkpoint_directory).trigger(availableNow=True).start()
```

Error Im getting states that:

> SET column ``` not found given columns:
> [`PK_D365_customeraddress`, `IsDelete`,  etc]

which is correct, `MSFT_DATASTATE` column is not in my silver deltatable.

Answer (score -1):

Ref: https://www.databricks.com/blog/2019/09/24/diving-into-delta-lake-schema-enforcement-evolution.html
Try and use this:

```
# Add the mergeSchema option
loans.write.format("delta") \
           .option("mergeSchema", "true") \
           .mode("append") \
           .save(DELTALAKE_SILVER_PATH)
```

Comment: Im working with stream data

Comment: it doesn't work with merge

Comment: @AlexOtt I had a schema evolution problem with two tables. Second table is fine. It adapted to new schema and new column was added in there. I have the question that you have answered and work well. But this kind of error with merge never had tho. I usually had this kind `Cannot resolve column1 in UPDATE clause given columns table.column2, etc`

Comment: I'll look when I have time

Comment: @AlexOtt hey, any update? still dont see from where the issue is coming from